# Angular strict mode, Ngrx, Jamsmine: mock selector with props

Tags: angular, jasmine, ngrx, strict-mode

I am currently trying to remove the deprecated selectors in my application.
This [github issue](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2980) telling us to declare selector with props as a function.

Old way (deprecated):

```
export const getCurrentScope = createSelector(getContextState, (state: ContextState, arg: string) => {
   return state.object + arg;
}
```

New Way:

```
export const getCurrentScope = (arg: string) => createSelector(getContextState, (state: ContextState) => {
   return state.object + arg;
}
```

With the deprecated method I was able to mock the selector by overriding it with the `overrideSelector` function.

Now that `getCurrentScope` is no longer a selector I cannot use the `overrideSelector` function.

So I'm trying to mock the function as follow:

```
import * as contextSelector from '@core/store/selectors/context.selectors';
spyOn(contextSelector, 'getCurrentScope').and.returnValue( ??? );
```

As I'm working with Angular Strict Mode, I have to return a MemoizedSelector but I do not find any way to perform it.

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: What is the exact error? Is it possible to create a stackblitz with that problem? It would be easier to investigate and try out different ideas to solve the issue.

Comment: I found a solution by calling the reals selectors and wait for their return to get the value but I found this very complicated.
I have no time for a stackBlitz now, the error is simply that the returnValue does not match with MemoizedSelector